# Posts in different orders on different pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So what I'm looking to do is to be able to have a link that shows the most recent posts and a link that shows the most liked or most viewed post and so on. I know how to change it for my entire application by going into my post controller and for example

```
def index
 @posts = Post.sort_by_popularity('DESC')
end
```

That sorts my posts by most viewed. But again it does it for my entire application. Again Im looking to have links that have my posts sorted differently for those pages. Can someone help me out on this. Im using Rails 4 by the way

This is what Ive tried but still no change

```
def index
@posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
 if params[:sort_param] == "views"
  @posts = Post.sort_by_popularity('DESC')

  elsif params[:sort_param] == "likes"
  @posts = Post.all.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)
 end
end
```

My links in my view

```
<li><%= link_to 'like', posts_path(:sort_param => "Most likes")%></li>
<li><%= link_to 'views', posts_path(:sort_param => "Most views")%></li>
```

Comment: you can create class methods for your different sortings and then call these methods in your controller actions based on some sorting parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `parameter` to the `index` method to sort:

```
def index
  if params[:sort_param] == "Like"
     // do something
  elsif params[:sort_param] == "date"
     // do something
  else
     @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

**In view**

```
%h3 Sort by:
= link_to 'Like', posts_path(:sort_param => "like")
%br
= link_to 'Date Updated', posts_path(:sort_param => "date")
```

Comment: Okay thank you. So is my def index supposed to look something like this? I did a quick edit to my question to see if I'm on the right track with what you are saying

Comment: @D.Graves, Yes you're on the right track. Is `cached_votes_up` is a column name on your `post` model? Also, assign the result to a instance variable like `@posts`

Comment: You mean on the posts table in the schema? Cause ya it is in that. But sort_by_popularity (views) is not.

Comment: @D.Graves, Answer updated. If `sort_by_popularity` is a `scope` then no problem.

Comment: Okay now maybe I'm just having an issue with my links then. Can I have them as just regular links? Ill post the links that I have right now. Im trying to put the links with the rest of my nav. but the way I have it now, it doesn't change when I click on them

Comment: links should be: `posts_path(:sort_param => "likes")` and `posts_path(:sort_param => "views")` as you're checking `views` and `likes` in your `index` method's if condition.

Comment: My bad I switched around the link and the name of the links. Its working perfectly now. Thank you so so much. You are a massive life savor!